Extended Events sessions stops collection when edited while the session is on run
I created an Extended Events session - based on Standard SQL template.
Just added Global filter on sqlserver.databasename for a particular DB.
Started watching live data.
Updated the session to edit it and added few more events. And clicked ok. The session was running during the edit happened.
Now the Watch live data stopped adding rows.
I did refresh the 'sessions' folder + the created session. But the Watch Live Data didn't resume.
Closed and opened again by right clicking the session name and chose 'Watch Live Data'. Now it shows 'Retrieving event information from server' but never adds up any events.
When checked the Target Data from eventfile. The last time it traced is before the edit happened. Though a day passed, the Target data never gets updated.
Have to create new session.
Does Extended Event session functions so?
Or Am I wrong? Kindly help. Can't keep creating new session for every edit we need.
Thank you!
Adding screenshot from Standard XEvent Profiler which is too not working.

Here is the script of the session - (Changed session name & DB name alone)
CREATE EVENT SESSION [SessionName] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.database_xml_deadlock_report(
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,package0.process_id,sqlos.cpu_id,SQLSatellite.AppName,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_connection_id,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.session_nt_username,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.transaction_id,sqlserver.transaction_sequence,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[database_name]=N'DBName')),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.existing_connection(SET collect_database_name=(1),collect_options_text=(1)
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,package0.process_id,sqlos.cpu_id,SQLSatellite.AppName,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_connection_id,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.session_nt_username,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.transaction_id,sqlserver.transaction_sequence,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[database_name]=N'DBName')),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_deadlock_chain(SET collect_database_name=(1),collect_resource_description=(1)
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,package0.process_id,sqlos.cpu_id,SQLSatellite.AppName,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_connection_id,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.session_nt_username,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.transaction_id,sqlserver.transaction_sequence,sqlserver.username)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_starting(SET collect_data_stream=(1)
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,package0.process_id,sqlos.cpu_id,SQLSatellite.AppName,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_connection_id,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.session_nt_username,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.transaction_id,sqlserver.transaction_sequence,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0)) AND [sqlserver].[database_name]=N'DBName')),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sp_statement_completed(SET collect_object_name=(1)
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,package0.process_id,sqlos.cpu_id,SQLSatellite.AppName,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_connection_id,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.session_nt_username,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.transaction_id,sqlserver.transaction_sequence,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[database_name]=N'DBName')),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed(
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,package0.process_id,sqlos.cpu_id,SQLSatellite.AppName,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_connection_id,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.session_nt_username,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.transaction_id,sqlserver.transaction_sequence,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[database_name]=N'DBName')),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_starting(
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,package0.process_id,sqlos.cpu_id,SQLSatellite.AppName,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_connection_id,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.session_nt_username,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.transaction_id,sqlserver.transaction_sequence,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0)) AND [sqlserver].[database_name]=N'DBName')),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(SET collect_parameterized_plan_handle=(1)
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,package0.process_id,sqlos.cpu_id,SQLSatellite.AppName,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_connection_id,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.session_nt_username,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.transaction_id,sqlserver.transaction_sequence,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[database_name]=N'DBName'))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'E:\SessionName.xel')
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=8192 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=5 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=PER_CPU,TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO

Event global filter which I mentioned is as below - to apply in all events


Add your XE session definition

Yes - added the script.

You might be in a mistake. There is not a Global Filter term in extended event sessions.
There are Global Fields and Session Event Filters.

You can easily start a session from XEvent Profiler> Standard> Lunch Session as in the following picture.

Then go right find database_name column. Right click then select Filter by this Value

For the problem you can check the Filters menu.
There could be a wrong string.


Dear FevziKartal, Thank you & Fine.
But issue is the session stopped and not getting started.  I need customized extended events . Could you please help?

You could use
ALTER EVENT SESSION Ex_Ev_Sess_name ON SERVER  STATE=START;
`

Yes, I checked it and its already in 'START' state.

So you have an XE session which truly is in started state (not just a refresh needed in the GUI) but it doesn't collect events?
Events that it does collect if you start over fresh?
If so, I would open a case with MS support.
Note that re-starting a trace (which happens after you modify a trace) will give you a new file, same as when the trace does a file-rollover. So make sure that you look in this new trace file.

Yes Tibor. You can reproduce it as I mentioned.
Edit a newly created session while you are watching it live. (session is in start mode)
Then you can try refreshing / close and open again Watch live data -
data won't be displayed.
I even tried stopping the same session and editing that same session again and then started the session. - But still no luck for me. I had to create completely new one with the needed things for me.

Or you can help me where I am going wrong.

Yes, I moved the old trace files ( of .xel) after stopping the session and then restarted the session. New file is getting created - But nothing is shown while watching live nor the file size increases.
